# Extract set of numbers from a string, subtract and then add them with certain exclusions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm not all that great with Excel formulas, I have an Excel column 'Logical Diskspace', each cell of which has a similar value as below.

```
 | DISK C: (NTFS)20.9731 GB (3.7077 GB Free Space)  | DISK E:
 (NTFS)107.3767 GB (22.7083 GB Free Space)  | DISK F: (NTFS)107.3767 GB
 (38.0516 GB Free Space)  | DISK G: (NTFS)53.6781 GB (21.7887 GB Free
 Space)  | DISK P: (NTFS)4.7252 GB (0.5997 GB Free Space)
```

What I need is to find the total used capacity excluding the C: drive.

Taking the above example, it should calculate as follows:

`Exclude C: + (107.3767-22.7083)+(107.3767-38.0516)+(53.6781-21.7887)+(4.7252-0.5997)`

Note that the number of drives may vary but would always be delimited by a '|' sign.

Could someone help me with a programmatic approach to achieve this?

Comment: You might to use regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: Instead of regular expressions you could also use the `split` function: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[excel-vba]+split

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not necessary but this would be very tedious to do more than one time without say Record Macro activated. Just a series of Find and Replace:

Find, in turn:

`Free Space) |DISK`
`Free Space)`
`: (NTFS)`
`GB`

and replace each with nothing (the first and last above start with a space).

Find `(` Replace with `-`
Find, in turn  `F`, `G` and `P` and replace each with `+`

Find `|DISK*E` and replace with `=`.

Comment: Not necessary, but still fun... FWIW, a quick macro I keep handy for bulk find-replace operations: `Sub rename()
    For Each c In Range("Table1[Column1]")
 Cells.Replace What:=(c.value) _
 , Replacement:=(c.offset(0,1).value) _
 , LookAt:=xlPart _
 , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
 , MatchCase:=False _
 , SearchFormat:=False _
 , ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next c
    msgbox "success"
End Sub`

Comment: yea, with only 1 row of sample input, it didn't seem prudent to demo out a sample post. Also, given the OP phrasing, I doubt anyone who could use the sub will look here for it, just wanted to include as a bonus followup to your answer.